# How to allow html in return of angular2 pipe?

Tags: pipe, angular

I have a pipe that returns a html string, however the string outputs escaped presumably as a default for security. I'm sure there must be an option to allow html instead but cant find it when I search docs.

How can I tell the pipe to allow actual html to render?

Answer (score 117):

Use bindings to [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) or [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) to render already escaped html. For example `<span [innerHTML]="someString | toHtmlPipe"></span>`. See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/458YlcYlHwDIRnQ6a2B9?p=preview):

```ts
@Pipe({
  name: 'wrapBold'
})
class WrapBold {
  transform(content) {
    return `<b>${content}</b>`;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  pipes: [WrapBold],
  template: `
    <div>
      Hello <span [outerHTML]="content | wrapBold"></span>
    </div>
  `
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.content = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting but not quite what I wanted, I think pipes probably aren't either, what I want is to be able to have a pipe or component perhaps called "hn" when you can use it in components lets say some kind of aggregate item where I want a header element such as a `h2` but I don't want to hardcode the `h2` because I think the component should be flexible enough so if when you use it when its proceeded by a h2 rather than a h1 you can tell it to use a h3. First tried `public var hn: string = 'h3';` and then trying this in template string `<{{hn}}>` failed so I was trying other options.

Comment: This answers exactly what you asked for. You should either update your answer to be more precise about what you're looking for or accept it.

Comment: In case you are wondering (like I was) about the `${content}` syntax, it is a TypeScript feature: [string interpolation](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html).  I learn a lot from @alexpods's answers.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Actually it's just es2015 [template strings expression interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings#Expression_interpolation) ([here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-template-literal-lexical-components) is the spec). It's already supported by almost all major browsers (for example try to wrtte `\`Date ${Date.now()}\`` in your chrome console).

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  I'm glad I can use this without TypeScript around.

Comment: What about pipe which returnes value but skip the possible others tags elements into it ? `<p [outerHTML]="result.label | super" ><span>{{  result.zip_code }}</span></p>`The entire span tag will replace by output filtering like this...

Comment: Is this answer still valid in the newer version of angular2? i cant seem to find the pipes  as @component metadata, as well as i got the error Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node. or did i missed something?

Comment: I'm also getting "Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node." when trying to assign to [outerHTML] property with pipe output.  That's disappointing, as outerHTML had also looked like a good solution for one-time binding as well.

Comment: Actually, assigning to outerHTML probably works once in each place it's used in markup, but then every time after, when Angular runs change detection, there is an error from trying to use outerHTML again on the same element, because the element is no longer attached to the DOM at that point.

Answer (score 14):

<strike>I don't know if that is possible with a pipe.</strike> (It is, see @alexpods's answer.)

Have you considered converting your pipe into a component with an input property?  I.e., whatever is feeding your pipe, make that an input property of the component.  Put the HTML that the pipe generates into the component's template.

Comment: I think this is the correct way of tackle this problem. Pipes are not the solution to modify html.

Comment: @Jesus There are legit reasons to do it (though the OP's use case doesn't fall under it). A simple example would be a "highlight" pipe, where you output some text with subsets highlighted based on what the user has searched for. Pipe's aren't a bad solution, and the only practical way to do this is to inject styled <span> tags within the text, thus the need for outputting html.

Answer (score 13):

So thanks for replies.

Using the outerHTML binding suggested by @alexpods worked a treat.
Didn't need to change my pipe at all.

So what I was doing before:

`{{'TEXT' | hn: 'h2.whatever'}}` which resulted in the correct html but escaped ie.

`&lt;h2 class="whatever"&gt;TEXT&lt;/h2&gt;`

Works great as: `<span [outerHTML]="'TEXT' | hn:'h2.whatever'"></span>`

which outputs: `<h2 class="whatever">TEXT</h2>`

Comment: Spoke to soon... It works however only the first time, if you are updating the view for example a menu that updates detail, the next time round it will fail with the following error "Failed to set the 'outerHTML' property on 'Element': This element has no parent node" presumably because of the previous transformation.

Comment: I think you need to set `pure: false` for your pipe.

Comment: I had the same issue, and I fixed it by changing `span` to `div` and using `innerHTML` instead of `outerHTML`, so for your example: `<div [innerHTML]="'TEXT' | hn:'h2.whatever'"></div>`