# Angular 2, interpolation HTML

Tags: angular, pipe, interpolation

I am creating a pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'highlight'
})
export class HighlightPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: string): any {
        let s = value + '';
        let startIdx = s.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase());
        let tokenLen = args.length;

        if (startIdx >= 0 && tokenLen > 0) {
            s = s.substring(0, startIdx) + '<strong>' + s.substring(startIdx, startIdx + tokenLen) + '</strong>' + s.substring(startIdx + tokenLen);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

To use like this:

```
<p>{{ result | highlight : search}}</p>
```

So if the result is 'Alabama' and my search is 'ba', I want this:

Ala**ba**ma

But I get the html tag:

```
Ala<strong>ba</strong>ma
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

You `pipe` should return

```
<strong>${content}</strong>
```

See more details [How to allow html in return of angular2 pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504203/how-to-allow-html-in-return-of-angular2-pipe)