# Angular: Rules on when to make something a custom pipe vs component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular-components, angular-pipe, angular2-custom-pipes

Any rules on when to use a custom **pipe** and when to use a custom **component**?

Could those be the rules of thumb (below) ?

- use a component if non-plaintext html is required? Inspired by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34504446/170451
- use pipe if something is not interactive (static output)?

Documentation does not seem to answer this question directly: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html

Could pipes be considered «poor man's components?»

---

Are there some advantages of **pipes** over **components**?

My guesses:

- shorter syntaxes / expressiveness
- performance benefits (build-time? run-time?)
- benefits when working with plain-text?

---

Does this statement (which is a guess written by me) hold true?

```
Everything that can be done with a pipe,
can be done (though perhaps at a higher cost) with a component as well?
```

Answer (score 1):

According to that same documentation:

> Pipes transform displayed values within a template

So if you are transforming displayed values, such as formatting a date or filtering a list, then a pipe makes sense.

If you are displaying HTML, use a component.

And the answer from 2015 for using innerHtml is not considered "best practices" and should be limited to only a last resort.

Comment: Thanks. Upvoted. Though, if one treats «Pipes transform displayed values within a template» in a very general way, one could say that components also «transform displayed values within a template» (in some very generic sense). Though I understand that there is a line to be drawn, given the criteria.