# Insert HTML into string

Tags: html, firebase, angular5

Using Angular 5 and Firebase, I have created a review website that allows users to create reviews on the `CreateComponent` and read them on the `ReviewComponent`. I'd like the body of the review to be able to contain HTML for links or images.

The `ReviewComponent` pulls the body of the review with:

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 2rem; white-space: pre-wrap;">{{review.body}}</p>
```

I am using `pre-wrap` to maintain the body's line breaks.

An example input from the `CreateComponent` would be:

`I already can’t wait to see <a href="http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/11/30/marvels-the-avengers-infinity-war-trailer-breakdown"> what comes next.</a>`

When I inspect the output of the body I see this:

`<p _ngcontent-c1 style="margin-bottom: 2rem; white-space: pre-wrap;">I already can’t wait to see &lt;a href="http://www.ign.com/articles/2017/11/30/marvels-the-avengers-infinity-war-trailer-breakdown"&gt;what comes next.&lt;/a&gt;</p>`.

How can I change the HTML to enable the string to work correctly with links and images?

Comment: I think you need to use a rich text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding `review.body` to `[innerHTML]` corrected this.

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 2rem; white-space: pre-wrap;">{{review.body}}</p>
```

is now

```
<p style="margin-bottom: 2rem; white-space: pre-wrap;" [innerHTML]="review.body"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solutions for your issue:

https://plnkr.co/edit/VHvVpvnTeoGWsA0d3eex?p=preview

Here is code:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, NgModule, VERSION, Pipe, PipeTransform, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div [outerHTML]='selectedValue | html'></div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  selectedValue: string = 'I already can’t wait to see <a href="https://www.ign.com/articles/2017/11/30/marvels-the-avengers-infinity-war-trailer-breakdown"> what comes next.</a>';
  constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }
}


@Pipe({
  name: 'html'
})
export class HtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string) {
      return `<div>${value}</div>`;
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ App, HtmlPipe ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You could write pipe for this application, like in this article:

[How to allow html in return of angular2 pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504203/how-to-allow-html-in-return-of-angular2-pipe)