# Replace link using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript, angular-pipe

**Flow:**

An array of strings comes from the server, for example, `["com"]` or `["c", "o", "m"]`.

**It is necessary:**

Highlight characters in links if there are matches with data that came from the server, that is, an array of strings.

**Angular pipe**

```
export class HighlightLettersPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(text: any, regexGroups?: string[]): any {
        if (text && regexGroups.length) {
            regexGroups.forEach(element => {
                let pattern = element.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, '\\$&');
                pattern = pattern.split(' ').filter((t) => {
                    return t.length > 0;
                }).join('|');

                let reg = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');
                text = text.replace(reg, match => {
                    return `<span class="replace-part">${match}</span>`;
                });
            });
            return text;
        } else {
            return text;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine when an array with one element arrives, for example `["com"]`.

[image]

**Problem**

When an array with several elements arrived - `["c", "o", "m"]`, the symbols are highlighted, but also the markup is inserted.

[image]

This is because the method `replace` is used, which returns a new line each time.

After making the first pass and making the highlighting of the characters, a new line is returned with an added `span` tag. Then a new pass is made and the symbols are already highlighted in the tag `span`, but it is necessary that only the symbols of the **original link** are always highlighted.

In the end something comes out:

[image]

Maybe someone has encountered a similar problem and will help solve it. Thank you.

Comment: your `Problem` part is very confusing.

Comment: You might have to use your pipe on `innerHTML`, see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34504203/how-to-allow-html-in-return-of-angular2-pipe) helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this trick: instead of replacing directly to `<span>` tags, add some placeholders like `~~~~~` for opening tag and `-----` for closing one, and replace that with actual tags afterwards. This way it will not collide

```
regexGroups.forEach(element => {
    // ...
    let reg = new RegExp(pattern, 'gi');
    text = text.replace(reg, match => {
        return `~~~~~${match}-----`;
    });
});

// this part must be outside your forEach() block
text = text.replace(/~~~~~/g, '<span class="replace-part">');
text = text.replace(/-----/g, '</span>');
```